# SpriteKit scene node scale clarification

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm working on a 2D iOS game and taking a crack at using the Scene builder in xCode for the first time.  So forgive me if this is rudimentary.

I've added a SKColorNode to the scene and by default it creates a small square.  So i resized that square to be a rectangle in the center of the screen about 80% total screen size.  By doing that, it changed the scale of that node to x:7.1,y:5.3.  Now i've added a few other color nodes as children of this one and applied textures to them.

When those nodes are children of the original rectangle, they have a scale of x:0.14,y:.188. But if I move them back to the parent scene they have a scale of x:1,y:1. After doing the math, i get where the numbers come from when they are children - (1 / 7.1 = 0.14) - but why is it doing that?

I need the scale to be 1-1 so when i want to animate a scale change with SKAction.scaleTo() i can just tell it to scale to double, or 50% larger, so on.  Without a 1-1 scale i'll have to retrieve and store the scale of those items before creating an animation.

Perhaps someone can tell me if i'm going about this wrong or it just is what is?

EDIT: This is what i'm doing as a workaround...

```
let overlay: SKSpriteNode!
let male: SKSpriteNode!
let female: SKSpriteNode!

overlayScaleFactorX = 1 / overlay.xScale
overlayScaleFactorY = 1 / overlay.yScale

male.run(SKAction.scaleX(to: overlayScaleFactorX * 1.2,y: overlayScaleFactorY * 1.2, duration: 0.2))

female.run(SKAction.scaleX(to: overlayScaleFactorX * 0.8,y: overlayScaleFactorY * 0.8, duration: 0.2))

male.run(SKAction.scaleX(to: overlayScaleFactorX * 0.8,y: overlayScaleFactorY * 0.8, duration: 0.2))

female.run(SKAction.scaleX(to: overlayScaleFactorX * 1.2,y: overlayScaleFactorY * 1.2, duration: 0.2))
```

I would like to just be able to do

```
male.run(SKAction.scale(to: 1.2,duration: 0.1))
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the Scene editor a lot, and it frustrates me a lot!. I can't understand why we cannot resize a SpriteNode in the editor without changing the scale. So, what I do is drag the "Color Sprite" on to the scene and drag and position to where I think it should go. I then look at the size in the Attributes Inspector, write those values down. I then change the scale back to 1,1 in the Attributes Inspector and then manually fill in the size values with the numbers I wrote down. Now when I do any scale or animation work on that node everything is as it should be.

Comment: Well thats just about as ridiculous as it gets, but does indeed work.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you found this useful please vote, or mark it as the correct answer.